# Library not loaded: ../../Bin/Release/libXnVNite_1_4_0.dylib

Tags: opencv, qt-creator, kinect, dyld, openni

When i'm making a project with openni. And have a problem when i make my makefile.

```
Starting /Users/olivierjanssens/Documents/ICT/Master/Thesis/Code/mysuperdemo/qtcreator-  build/mysuperdemo...
dyld: Library not loaded: ../../Bin/Release/libXnVNite_1_4_0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/olivierjanssens/Documents/ICT/Master/Thesis/Code/mysuperdemo/qtcreator-build/mysuperdemo
Reason: image not found
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

My cmake file

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

 PROJECT(mysuperdemo)

 SET(NESTK_USE_OPENNI 1)
 ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(nestk)
 ## nestk/UseNestk.cmake.in defines variable to use nestk.
 ## It itself includes nestk/deps/cmake/UseEmbeddedNestkDeps.cmake that
 ## contains most of the cmake find packages commands.
 INCLUDE("${nestk_BINARY_DIR}/UseEmbeddedNestk.cmake")

ADD_EXECUTABLE(mysuperdemo mysuperdemo.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mysuperdemo nestk)
```

this generates my makefile which i then make.

The file mentioned in the error is not on my system ( ../../Bin/Release/libXnVNite_1_4_0.dylib). Though there is a libXnVNite.dylib file but not in the ../../Bin/Release/ folder that which does not exist. I work on osx 10.7

any idea how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this i renamed the existing libXnVNite.dylib to libXnVNite_1_4_0.dylib and created a folder /bin/release relative to my application and deposited the file in it. It works but i think it is far from a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution would be to create symlinks in that relative folder.
../../Bin/Release/libXnVNite_1_4_0.dylib -> /usr/lib/libXnVNite.dylib

and so on for all the problematic libraries.

That worked once for me, but now it's just working anymore...

An even more elegant solution would be to use install_name_tool to change those relative paths to the real ones.